# d3.js not understanding svg:path

Tags: d3.js

I really want to do line chart which updates and I was studying below

https://gist.github.com/benjchristensen/1148374

And one thing I ran into for first time is:

```
graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
            // or it can be done like this
            //graph.selectAll("path").data([data]).enter().append("svg:path").attr("d", line);
```

svg:path?    What is this suppose to mean?

Comment: I guess it's just way to distinguish using name space scheme. I went ahead with just using graph.append("path") since there are only one path in specific example I am building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you don't need the "svg:" part these days.

Long Answer: It's an XML namespace for mixed type documents (e.g., XHTML & SVG): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace